# Google Calendar API -- Benefits of Client ID vs Service Account

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I was wondering if somebody could explain to me the benefits and drawbacks of using Client IDs vs. using a Google Service Account if I want to integrate Google Calendar API into my app.

This video did not explain the benefits/drawbacks very clearly:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lVSLsE7z8U

I also read this post. [What's the difference between api key, client id and service account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181501/whats-the-difference-between-api-key-client-id-and-service-account)
It says that if I use Client IDs, then the user would be granting the app access to some of his/her Google Account's info.

However, I would like more concrete examples of what I would be able to do/accomplish or not do/accomplish as a developer using Client IDs vs using Google Service Account. In the context of integrating Google Calendar API.

Comment: Its not about the client id really, its more about how the authorization is setup and which scenarios they are best suited for.  I wrote these articles several years ago they might help. [Google Developer Console Oauth2 credentials](https://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-oauth2/)  vs [Google Developer console service account](https://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-service-account/) vs [Google developer console API key](https://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-create-public-api-key/)   Those articles have your concrete examples.